# target=_blank opening with same url

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I added HyperLink control in my page.  When I enter "http://www.google.com", It is opening in new window (good) and pointing google.

**1. When I enter "www.google.com", It is opening in new window, but Url is "http://mysite.com/www.google.com". Why this is happing? How to should point to www.google.com**

```
<a href= '<%# Eval("ConferenceUrl") %>'  runat ="server" id="ConferenceUrl" 
target="_blank"> <%# Eval("ConferenceUrl")%> </a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<%# Eval("ConferenceUrl") %>` needs to have the `http://` prefix. Either change your data or add it to the `href` attribute.

```
<a href= 'http://<%# Eval("ConferenceUrl") %>'  runat ="server" id="ConferenceUrl" target="_blank"> <%# Eval("ConferenceUrl")%> </a>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need `http://` in the url, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add http:// in the beginning of href